# How to access iframes using scripting API?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have a chrome extension I need to access all the iframes on the attached page using the scripting API

```json
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "My example extension",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "permissions": ["tabs", "scripting"],
  "devtools_page": "devtools.html",
  "host_permissions": [
    "<all_urls>"
  ]
}
```

I can run the script on the inspectedWindow easily enough

```js
// devtools.html -> js
chrome.devtools.panels.create("Sample Panel", "icon.png", "/panel.html", panel => {
  // code invoked on panel creation
});
```

```js
// panel.html -> js
chrome.scripting.executeScript({
    target: { tabId: chrome.devtools.inspectedWindow.tabId },
    injectImmediately: true,
    func: () => {
        console.log('foo')
    }
})
```

I want this script to run on the page and all children iframes immediately (before anything else is run, just like a content_script).

It seems this only runs on the host page. When I try to query for child iframes, it doesn't seem to find anything

```js
> await chrome.tabs.query({ windowId: chrome.devtools.inspectedWindow.tabId })
// []
```

Did I miss a permission?

Comment: The iframe content won't be loaded immediately on page load. Similar to images, src'd javascript, and link'd css, they don't load until after the page source loads.

Comment: Add `allFrames: true` as shown in the documentation.

Comment: @wOxxOm I think that's only for content_scripts right?

Comment: executeScript injects content scripts, indeed. Anyway, see the documentation.